# QGIS hides few graduated points after reopening project

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, style, symbology

I have a strange problem in QGIS 2.2 (problem is also present in QGIS 2.1).
When I add a point (shapefile) layer, apply graduated style and change point size, everything looks fine. Then I save project, reopen it, and some of the points are missing.

When I open attribute table all points are there, but some of them are not shown on the map. Usually those point are in the middle of the map. I noticed that number of mising points depends on selected "on the fly" CRS (before save). When I remove graduated style then all points show up on the map... Zooming, refreshing view and changing projection doesn't help.

[image: Before save]

[image: After save]

Comment: What values do the missing points have? Does it get better if you start your graduate style at 0.9?

Comment: I use 5 classes with equal interval from 0.9999 to 1.0002.
I tried using 0.9 but it doesn't help.

Comment: Example of point value: 0.9999017173

Comment: Ok, I just tried to change lower value to 0.9 and upper value to 1.1, and it works! This much better solution than the first one I accidentally came up. Is this expected behavior of QGIS, or some kind of bug? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you encountered some kind of rounding error when writing the graduated style to the project file.

Try with some larger intervall, like 0.99 to 1.01